# Monaco Editor: Setting Font Size Using API?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm able to set the `fontSize` property when creating a Monaco Editor instance. However, I'd like to provide my users with the ability to change the size during runtime. I can't find an API that I can call to update the font size. I would've hoped for something like `editor.setFontSize(20)`, but perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out!

The `editor` object has an `updateOptions` method that takes an `IEditorOptions` dictionary. Therefore,

```
let options = {"fontSize": 20}
editor.updateOptions(options);
```

accomplishes the task. [Here's a complete list of the options available](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.ieditoroptions.html).